# VBA to hide all worksheets in future months (MMM YYYY)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with sheets for the months of the financial year ("JUL 2021" through to "JUN 2022"). Im hoping to hide sheets corresponding to future months.

I've tried:

```
  Dim ws As Worksheet

  Dim strMonth As String

  strMonth = Format(Date, "MMM YYYY")

  For Each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

  If ws.Name <= strMonth Then

        ws.Visible = True

  Else

        ws.Visible = False

  End If

  Next ws
```

However, that is hiding all worksheets after current months by alphabetical order, not month.

I know it will be something really simple, I've only been using VBA for about a week so any help is appreciated

Comment: Flip the logic. Instead of formatting today's date as a string, keep it `Date`, and then programmatically find the equivalent date from the sheet names. Then you can compare dates against each other, instead of comparing text representations of a date.

Comment: Ok... So what I need to do is Dim worksheet name as [X], and then run CDate on "01 "& [X], then compare to today's date? (Sorry, as noted, I've only been using VBA for a week) Correction: I would need to extract today's date as DD then add it to the worksheet name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of comparing text representations of a date, you could convert the worksheet names to dates using `CDate` (e.g. JUL 2021 becomes July 1, 2021) and then compare directly to `Date`.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If IsDate(ws.Name) Then
        ws.Visible = (CDate(ws.Name) < Date)
    End If
Next
```

If you want to compare to month-end (e.g. JUL 2021 becomes July 31, 2021), then one option is `WorksheetFunction.EoMonth`:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If IsDate(ws.Name) Then
        Dim tempDate As Date
        tempDate = WorksheetFunction.Eomonth(CDate(ws.Name), 0)

        ws.Visible = (tempDate < Date) ' or maybe <=
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You're welcome! I added a version for if you want to compare to the month-end instead of the beginning of the month.

Comment: So that would only show the worksheet if the end of the month has passed?

Comment: Correct. If you change `<` to `<=`, then the worksheet also be visible on the last day of the month. Really once you have a date using `CDate`, you can adjust it as you please (keep it the first of the month, make it mid-month, end-of-month, next month...)

Comment: Hey BigBen, sorry if this is really cheeky but would you mind having a look at my latest question?